# how to play an audio file which is not in the main bundle?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, mp3, avplayer

this is my code to play mp3 file from the directory of the application, and for some reason it's not working. lease find out what's wrong with this code !

```
   -(IBAction)PlayLesson:(id)sender;
 {
NSString *folderAndFile = @"/Users/alaaalfadhel/Library/Application Support/iPhone        Simulator/5.1/Applications/1021CF5B-F664-4123-B9CB-529217225B74/Documents/file.mp3";
NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,               NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderAndFile];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioFilePath];
                                         ofType:@"mp3"]];
   AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

    [click play];
 }
```

Comment: Before calling `initWithContentsOfURL:` insert `NSLog(@"Path: %@, URL: %@", audioFilePath, url);`.  What does it print?

Comment: Path: /Users/alaaalfadhel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/5515AFBA-1E7D-4B06-A62E-F6FDFD7DD7C7/Documents/Users/alaaalfadhel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/1021CF5B-F664-4123-B9CB-529217225B74/Documents/file.mp3, 
URL:file://localhost/Users/alaaalfadhel/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/5515AFBA-1E7D-4B06-A62E-F6FDFD7DD7C7/Documents/Users/alaaalfadhel/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/1021CF5B-F664-4123-B9CB-529217225B74/Documents/file.mp3

Answer (score 0):

Since the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` supplies everything up to the Documents directory, you don't need to give it a folder/file combination but just the file.

You really want your URL to be /Users/alaaalfadhel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/5515AFBA-1E7D-4B06-A62E-F6FDFD7DD7C7/Documents/file.m‌​p3 instead of the one displayed in your log.  This is necessary because the long hex value will change any time you remove the app from the simulator and then launch it again.

Comment: how can i remove the file://localhost/Users from my URL

Comment: Sorry...that should be OK.  It was the duplicate path portion from /Users/ to /Documents/ that I was objecting to.